# Why is liquid germanium denser than solid germanium?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, semiconductors

Why are some elements like Ge and Si have liquids denser than their solids? In water it is explainable by H bonding, but no H bonds or such are there in Ge and Si.
Well, I want an explanation about the structure formed by Ge and Si in their solid state which makes them less dense than their liquids, and also the bonds formed

Comment: If this helps, (I have taken this from @matt_black answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/55091/50406).) "There isn't really a simple single explanation of why some solids are less dense than their associated liquids. The general explanation (which doesn't really explain much) is that the solid has a structure and, sometimes, that structure takes us more space than the average structure that occurs in the liquid."

Comment: Thanks for that Zenix, but I wanted a more detailed answer, so I modified the question accordingly as well.

Comment: Si and Ge are 4-fold coordinated diamond structure semiconducting solids. Their liquids are 8 to 12-fold coordinates metallic phases. The diamond crystal structure is fairly open.

Comment: Gallium and bismuth are also more dense, as liquids near their melting points, than are their respective solids at room temperature.

Comment: Don’t forget antimony as well...